# format date as desired format using javascript/moment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, jsx

I need the data as Jun 1st, 2021. I need to use this in react. Could some one help how to get in this format using moment/javascript.

Comment: try referring docs https://momentjs.com/ as well

Comment: A much more compact library (vs momentjs) is [dayjs](https://day.js.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with moment you can use this - moment().format('MMM Do, YYYY');